# Detect if a Recyclerview row overlaps with a FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an app with a Recyclerview and a FAB at the bottom, I also have an ad integrated in the list as a row, I need to detect when the ad row scrolls down and goes under the fab to disable the ad so it doesn't get clicked accidentally if the user presses the FAB, how can I detect if a list row is under a fab?

[image]

Comment: Is your Ad is in the last item of your ```Recyclerview```?

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then modify your question.

Comment: ad is not in the last item